# WPF Window doesn't SizeToContent correctly when Child Visibility set to Collapsed on Load

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm running into an odd issue with a WPF Window I'm calling `.ShowDialog()` on.

I have `SizeToContent="Height"`, and it kind of works.  Initially the size is 300 (the default for WPF Windows), and when I show the dialog, it shrinks to the size of its children.  However, one of the children disappears depending on properties of the dialog (intentionally), and the window doesn't resize to reflect this.  It instead just leaves a black space.

[image: Window with black space]

What's really strange is if, in the `Window_Loaded` handler, I call `MessageBox.Show("foo");`, it does resize properly.

[image: Message box]

[image: Window resized correctly]

I'm guessing this is some quirk of the Dispatcher or renderer, or some race condition I don't understand.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  This is a very minor side project, so a hack to get it to redraw or resize, rather than "doing it right" is perfectly fine.

In case it's important, here's the code:

#### AnxietyTracker.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Wages.AnxietyTracker"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xkct="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wages"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Track Anxiety" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        SizeToContent="Height">
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="0 4 0 0" Visibility="{Binding Path=InitialVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
            <TextBlock Margin="4 0">Initial anixety</TextBlock>
            <xkct:IntegerUpDown Name="iudInitial" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Margin="4 0" Increment="5" Value="0" KeyDown="iudInitial_KeyDown" />
        </DockPanel>
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=IntervalVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="4 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Peak anxiety</TextBlock>
            <xkct:IntegerUpDown Name="iudPeak" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Margin="4 0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Increment="5" Value="0"
                                KeyDown="iudPeak_KeyDown" />
            <TextBlock Margin="4 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Current anxiety</TextBlock>
            <xkct:IntegerUpDown Name="iudCurrent" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Margin="4 0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Increment="5" Value="0"
                                KeyDown="iudInitial_KeyDown" />
        </Grid>
        <Button Name="btnSubmit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4" Click="btnSubmit_Click">Submit</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### AnxietyTracker.xaml.cs

```
// using ...
namespace Wages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AnxietyTracker.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AnxietyTracker : Window
    {
        public enum TrackState
        {
            Initial,
            Interval,
            End
        }

        private TrackState m_trackState;

        public AnxietyTracker(TrackState state)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_trackState = state;
        }

        public int CurrentAnxiety { get; set; }
        public int PeakAnxiety { get; set; }

        public Visibility InitialVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_trackState == TrackState.Initial)
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }

                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public Visibility IntervalVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_trackState != TrackState.Initial)
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }

                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        // handlers for irrelevant stuff ...

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window w = sender as Window;
            w.Activate();

            if (CurrentAnxiety != 0)
            {
                iudCurrent.Value = CurrentAnxiety;
            }

            if (PeakAnxiety != 0)
            {
                iudPeak.Value = PeakAnxiety;
            }

            if (iudInitial.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                iudInitial.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                iudPeak.Focus();
            }

            // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("foo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My immediate guess would be that your StackPanel is not resizing properly when you collapse the Grid. meaning that the window will maintain the original size. Have you looked at that?. Stack panels tend to irritate me on occasion, so i tend to hold everything in a Grid, as i can typically control the results better

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't know how I would go about checking/debugging that.

Comment: You could try adding `Height=Auto` to the StackPanel. Or replacing the StackPanel with a dock panel or a grid with an auto height. If the problem persists with those, it may need more digging.

Comment: I just tried all three of those, and the behavior stayed the same.

Comment: I dont have a dev environment in front of me. I can try a little later.

Comment: Am aware that this is an old post, but you're just missing the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.